# A Database.Esqueleto riddle regarding ==. val True

Tags: haskell, persistent, esqueleto

While debugging a query that unexpectedly returned an empty list, I realized that I wrote something silly:

```
fetchDim cId = runDb . select . from $ \dim -> do
  where_ dim ^. DimensionIsRowKey ==. val True
  return dim
```

... because you can append `== True` to any Boolean value. Replacing it with the following unexpectedly solved my problem and the result wasn't an empty list anymore.

```
fetchDim cId = runDb . select . from $ \dim -> do
  where_ dim ^. DimensionIsRowKey
  return dim
```

Anyone can enlighten me about the actual difference between the two? Why would there be any?

EDIT: The database backend is sqlite.

Comment: Sure looks like a [bug](https://github.com/prowdsponsor/esqueleto/issues) to me

Comment: What database backend were you using?

Comment: edited the question.